# Select and count where result is elsewhere

Tags: mysql, select

I have a Table like following:

```
ID | Name              | Type        | State            | County
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Rheinland-Pfalz   | State       | Rheinland-Pfalz  | NULL
2  | Trier             | City        | Rheinland-Pfalz  | NULL
3  | Alzey-Worms       | County      | Rheinland-Pfalz  | Alzey-Worms
4  | Alzey             | City        | Rheinland-Pfalz  | Alzey-Worms
5  | Worms             | City        | Rheinland-Pfalz  | Alzey-Worms
6  | Lorem             | County      | Rheinland-Pfalz  | Lorem
7  | Ipsum             | City        | Rheinland-Pfalz  | Lorem
```

Now I want to get all Counties within the state "Rheinland-Pfalz" and their included cities and all countie free cities.

Wished Result:

```
ID | Name          | Type        | Included         
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | Trier         | City        | NULL  
3  | Alzey-Worms   | County      | 2  
6  | Lorem         | County      | 1
```

My Query:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.type,
                (select count(*) from data where a.type="city" AND b.county=a.county) as included
                from data as a, data as b
                WHERE a.location_type='county' AND a.state = 'Rheinland-Pfalz' OR a.type='city' AND a.gmap_area1 = 'Rheinland-Pfalz' AND a.county IS NULL
                order by a.name asc
```

My Result:

```
ID | Name          | Type        | Included         
-------------------------------------------------------------------
3  | Alzey-Worms   | County      | 0  
3  | Alzey-Worms   | County      | 0  
3  | Alzey-Worms   | County      | 0  
3  | Alzey-Worms   | County      | 0  
3  | Alzey-Worms   | County      | 0
```

.... AND SO ON

Comment: Does the above query work?

Comment: @AT-2016: No, i updated the Post with my result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be shy to use parenthesis

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.name, 
    a.type, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data 
        WHERE type='city' AND county=a.county) AS included 
FROM data AS a 
WHERE 
    a.state='Rheinland-Pfalz' AND 
    (a.type='county' OR (a.type='city' AND a.county IS NULL));
```

Comment: A W E S O M E! Thanks a lot! Wasn't that far away :)

Answer (score 0):

one way you could try group clause - not tested:

```
select count(*) from data where type in ('state','County') where
   state = 'Rheinland-Pfalz' group by type,state;
```

Also to consider is the ID or detailed field level values will not appear in counts

Comment: Try adding the fields in the select stamens and group by them - detail level fields like id's should not be included

Comment: ...Select name, type, count(*) ... Group by name, type